# PC Boots into bios, windows loading screen, then monitor loses signal

Tags: boot, windows-8.1, bios, nvidia-geforce

I have an irritating problem.
My pc will post, allow me to enter bios setup to change settings and whatnot. When attempting to boot either to the windows boot manager, or the windows 8.1 setup disk, the monitor loses signal after the logo is presented and spinner spins for a moment.

I have been through 2 motherboards thinking that might be the issue.
Asus Z170 Premium (currently installed)
MSI Z170A Gaming

I have a nVidia Titan Z installed, but 2 Radeon 390s sitting around. I have attempted a swap for one of the 390s to get it going with no luck.

The keyboard and mouse have power, all my fans are running and the lights are on.

BIOS version 2.17.1246 on the ASUS board.

I am generally ok with dealing with this sort of thing, but I am at a loss.

Update: 
Attempted a boot from an old windows 7 startup disk and got a black screen with a pointer sitting in the center unable to move.